# How to stop a unstoppable Kernel Driver windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, services, kernel

I am looking to stop a kernel-level service. I  would like to stop the service called BadlionAnticheat (not going to cheat in online games don't worry). When I `sc query` BadlionAnticheat, I get the following output:

```
SERVICE_NAME: BadlionAnticheat
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

When I `sc interrogate` it, I get the same info. Before I try to use `sc stop` on it, though, it does say it is stoppable, and I get the following message trying to stop it:

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc stop BadlionAnticheat
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1052:

The requested control is not valid for this service.
```

I can stop it by simply setting the start= disabled in `sc config` but that requires restarting the computer and I do not want to do that. I do not care if I break the application that uses BadlionAnticheat.

So, my question: Is there a way to stop this from running, without having to restart my computer?

Answer (score 0):

When the .inf file contains

```
PnPLockdown=1
```

That makes it harder to remove the driver.
You can still call

```
sc delete BadlionAnticheat
```

and reboot.
However, as long as `PnPLockdown` is set to `1`, `stop` won't work.

See: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/kernel-driver-you-want-ruth-haephrati-qjfhe